# React-Bootstrap Cards Stretching Images

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am simply trying to set up some cards in React-Bootstrap but the Card component is stretching my images way bigger than their original sizes. When I try putting the image in an  tag outside of the card, the images display at their normal sizes. Can anyone help with advice on how to prevent the image stretching? I am simply using the code example from the React-Bootstrap website:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Container, Row, Col, Card, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';
import logo from "./Assets/Logo.png"
import talkie from "./Assets/Talkie.png"
import rabbit from "./Assets/Rabbit.png"
import shield from "./Assets/Shield.png"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    
    <Container>
      <Row className="flex-nowrap">
        <Col md={6} sm={6} xs={6} align="left">
        <img  className="nav-logo img-fluid" src={logo}/> 
        </Col>   
        <Col md={6} sm={6} xs={6} className="contactLink" align="right">
          contact
          </Col>
      </Row>
      </Container>
    
      <Container className="px-4" style={{paddingTop: "3%"}}>
        <Row >
          <Col >
      <Card className="cards" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src={talkie}   />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
</Col>
   </Row>
  </Container>
```

[image: my image stretched]

Comment: Hi Gass, yes I've tried that but it still distorts the image.

Comment: Hi Gass thanks for the follow up. I edited the post to show a snippet of what I have in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So mainly what you need is to add the `object-fit: none` style property to the Image element inside your cards. This will prevent the image from resizing and it will maintain its original size.

You can read more about `object-fit` css property here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Try the following code in your `App.js`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>

      <Container>
        <Row className="flex-nowrap">
          <Col md={6} sm={6} xs={6} align="left">
            <img className="nav-logo img-fluid" src={logo} />
          </Col>
          <Col md={6} sm={6} xs={6} className="contactLink" align="right">
            contact
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>

      <Container className="px-4" style={{ paddingTop: "3%", maxHeight: '14rem' }}>
        <Row style={{ maxHeight: '15rem' }} >
          <Col >

            {/* first card */}
            <Card className="cards" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
              <div style={{ height: '120px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <Image src={talkie} style={{ objectFit: 'none', marginTop: '10px' }} alt="talkie" />
              </div>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                  the card's content.
                </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col>

            {/* second card */}
            <Card className="cards" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
              <div style={{ height: '120px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <Image src={shield} style={{ objectFit: 'none', marginTop: '15px' }} alt="talkie" />
              </div>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                  the card's content.
                </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>

          <Col>

            {/* third card */}
            <Card className="cards" style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
              <div style={{ height: '120px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                <Image src={rabbit} style={{ objectFit: 'none', marginTop: '30px' }} alt="talkie" />
              </div>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                  the card's content.
                </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>

        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

**Note:** I added aditional styles and a `div` that wraps the `Image` element to improve the aesthetics of the cards.

Comment: Thank you! This worked in stopping my image from stretching. I still had a problem with the card itself being stretched tall as it was before. I then read closer and saw you prevented that from happening in the <div>'s height holding the image. I wonder why the card would stretch so much in the first place. Anyhow, thank you for your help.

Comment: `I wonder why the card would stretch so much in the first place` It might just be the default way of Bootstrap to deal with images inside cards. It stretches them in relation to their ratio to fit the card. And so the ratio of your image is thin and long.

Comment: I see, I thought I might have had some bad css going on that was causing the problem. It was all very confusing - thanks for your help!